# Зачем нужен new Proxy в js?

Tags: javascript

Я смотрел видеоурок по Proxy и щас сижу думаю , а зачем он вообще нужен , а то я не понимаю все равно в чем его смысл , мне кажется и без него можно обойтись . Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: толковые примеры, а также задачи для самостоятельного решения есть в [статье про Proxy](https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy). как я понял, они нужны для создателей фреймвоков и библиотек, обычному разработчику они без надобности

Comment: Обойтись можно много без чего. Лучше [документацию почитайте](https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy) или на [developer.mozilla.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Видео уроки не всегда описывают все возможности применения. Найти применение можно в разных областях. По крайней мере знать о такой возможности необходимо